# How to create Categories in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, categories

i'm trying to Add Categories to my Rails app, but don't quite know how to do this.

I have many Pins(Images) and want the user to be able to assign a category on those Pins.
**ASSIGN** not create, edit, or delete a Category, just selecting one for their Pin.
Meaning that, When a user uploads a pin, he can choose from a dropdown list a Category.

Then, another user can choose from the Menu a Category, and ONLY the Pins in this Category will be listed.

How do i do this? Where to start ?

Thank you

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First If you don't want to manage categories in your application, then you can simply add a category field in your table and category select in your application :

```
<%= f.select :category, [ 'Box', 'Cover', 'Poster' ], :prompt => 'Select One' %>
```

Second, If you want to manage categories in your application, than you have to maintain a separate model and table for it. So you can start with generating your model:

```
rails g model category
```

it will add model and migration in your application directory. Add stuff to your migration:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      ## you can add more stuff as per your requirements 
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Define associations in category & Pin model add validation for this :-

```
In Category Model:
  has_many :pins

In Pin Model :
  belongs_to :category
  validates :category, presence: true
```

Create some categories by categories controller and form (I don't think, I need to tell you that stuff, you are able to do it yourself)

In your pin uploading form add this select :-

```
<%= f.select :category, Category.all, :prompt => "Select One" %>
```

Hope, It will help.

Comment: Rails Guy you Rock, Thank you very much. But i have one Question: I did all the above. Now, i create a Categories Controller? wouldn't that allow the users to create categories too? Sry if this question seems to you too noobish, im fairly new to Rails. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can add, remove, edit and delete your categories. Add your methods in your controller and templates in your views. Now you are good to go. Please accept the answer if you got what you were looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I think you didn't understood me right!, I'm fairly new to Rails and have some troubles understanding. Sry for that. Now, if i create a controller, the user has the ability to go to site.com/categories and create categories. I don't want that. I just want to set the Categories and the user should only CHOOSE from the List.

Comment: Please share your pin form view code. I will maje necessary changes in it.

Comment: I suggest you two options, I think, you didn't look into my first option. Add a column in your pin table and a select in you /app/views/pins/_form.html.erb template above the pinname input and add your options in your select in place of 'Box','Cover' etc as I suggested in first option :

<%= f.select :category, [ 'Box', 'Cover', 'Poster' ], :prompt => 'Select One' %>

Don't follow any step from second option in my answer, and if you did, revert that code as you don't need category management in your application. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33839/discussion-between-the-mini-john-and-rails-guy)

Comment: Hey Rails Guy - do you have a email where i can ask u a small (for you) Question ?:)

Comment: Yes, you can. shoot me a mail on vish_agni1985@yahoo.com..
One thing I want to let you know that the serial upvoting done by you on my answers, however all got reversed. what you should have do to upvote my accepted answers, So I would have got a little boost but not all got reversed. Now see that blood red -160 in my profile. BTW thanks for the good intention. :)

Comment: @RailsGuy Sorry for interrupting, I have a question which kind of follows this discussion - after creating these categories, what code do I have to put in the view/controller in order to filter out items by categories? I am reading the Rails Routing guide, but so far it seems very confusing. Thanks.

Comment: @Denis G Just one question, which option have you chosen from my above answer. do you have category field in your Pin model, or you have a different model named category ?

Comment: @RailsGuy I actually went my own way before I stumbled upon this thread, so I have events (belongs_to types) and types (has_many events). In my view I have <%= link_to event.type.name, '#' %> , which I would like to make clickable in order to filter the events by type on a current page

Comment: @Denis G Okay, As I understand, on the link click, you want to send an Ajax request and fetch all the events belongs to that type, and show it on the page without refreshing the page. Am I right?

Comment: @RailsGuy No, AJAX is not important at this point. I just want to user click on the tag and router sends him to a page with all the events with the same tag.

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna add a `def to_s` method on your Category model. I believe it will display some weird memory address code just by using plain `Category.all` on the `f.select` option. Everything else looks great!