# Ruby on rails How to create form select helper to list all option from a table column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Category Model. I want to let user select category for their post. The Model has only name. It's one model to many categories relationship. 
Here is my code

```
<%= f.select :category, Category.all, :prompt => "Select One" %>
```

I learnt it from rails guy [How to create Categories in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758401/how-to-create-categories-in-rails)

I want to display the name but it shows some weird option.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :category, Category.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, :prompt => "Select One" %>
```

Try this

Comment: Hi thanks for your help can you explain a little bit "map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}" Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this i hope this will help.

```
<%= f.select :category, Category.all.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, prompt: "Select One" %>
```