# Create categories in rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to create categories in my app:
I got inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758401/how-to-create-categories-in-rails)

But when @RailsGuy says: "Create some categories by categories controller and form (I don't think, I need to tell you that stuff, you are able to do it yourself)"
I felt lost...

How and where do I create my list of categories? dogs, cats, birds...
I saw that it could be done in the console but  I will display a different pictures for each categories...

Here is my _form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for @tuto do |f|
  - if @tuto.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      h2 = "#{pluralize(@tuto.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this tuto from being saved:"
      ul
        - @tuto.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          li = message
  = f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
  = f.input  :title
  = f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose Category"}
  = f.input :content, as: :text, input_html: { rows: "15" }
  = f.button :submit, "Save"
```

**my models:**

tuto_model.rb

```
class Tuto < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  validates :category, presence: true
end
```

categoty_model.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tutos
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160920133801) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "tutos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  add_index "tutos", ["user_id"], name: "index_tutos_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.boolean  "admin"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "votable_id"
    t.string   "votable_type"
    t.integer  "voter_id"
    t.string   "voter_type"
    t.boolean  "vote_flag"
    t.string   "vote_scope"
    t.integer  "vote_weight"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "votes", ["votable_id", "votable_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_votable_id_and_votable_type_and_vote_scope"
  add_index "votes", ["voter_id", "voter_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_voter_id_and_voter_type_and_vote_scope"

end
```

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the pictues stored in assets. And in the form/view use a conditional?:

`<% if tuto.category == dog %>
  <%= image_tag 'dog.jpg' %>
<% end %>`

Something like that?

Steve.

Answer (score 1):

The other post says to use the controller and form to create new categories. If you used scaffold to create the model Category, you'll have the `new` & `create` action in the controller and a `new.html.erb` and `index.html.erb` (or.slim if you're using that).

You can create your categories in there, then select one in your Tuto model.

Make sense?

Steve.

Comment: I need default categories :) like "Dogs, cats, birds"

Comment: If you hard-code the instances of `Category` and ensure there's nothing in the `new` or `create` action, or something restricting those actions to admin only, then there will only be the ones you create available to your users. You could create them via console in your production environment, or as an admin user.

Comment: I know for the console... but I am not sure it will work with the corresponding picture... if this item is selected display this image... you see?
It has to be in the code... but I don't know how :'(

Comment: Hey you read in my mind, that's what I was  trying.... maybe Iwill finally use the console  ;)